# QuartzCode and Swift, how to show in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, quartzcode

I have made simple loader (custom progress indicator) inside QuartzCode app and in my new Xcode project I imported two file that have QuartzCode exported.

Can you please tell me how to show it, hot to start that animation? I have inserted in my storyboard UIView and connected class from imported QuartzCode .swift files, but animation is not showing. I see static image (suppose first frame), but not animation.

If someone has played with QuartzCode and it's animations, can you please tell me how to insert animations to my app?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.quartzcodeapp.com/code-generation/how-to-use-code/

Comment: Thanks @matt :) I didn't see that. Going immediately to try it out. Thanks again.